# Column/Line in R

Tags: r

In R, i have a table where the column name is a date, how do I invert the columns by rows to be able to record in the database?

Example Table:

```
 estab  codigo               descricao 2021-02-01 2021-02-02
1    103 4390160                ANM 2003          0          0
2    103 4390161             ANM 2004 MF          0          0
3    103 4390162             ANM 2008 MF          0          0
4    103 4390193             ANM 3004 ST          0          0
5    103 4390189             ANM 3008 ST          0          0
6    103 4543512              ANM 24 NET          0          0
7    103 4390163             AMT 2008 RF          0          0
8    103 4543520    ANM 2003 COM BATERIA          0          0
9    103 4543521 ANM 2004 MF COM BATERIA          0          0
10   103 4543522 ANM 2008 MF COM BATERIA          0          0
11   103 4543523 ANM 3004 ST COM BATERIA          0          0
12   103 4543524 ANM 3008 ST COM BATERIA          0          0
13   103 4543516                AMT 8000          0          0
14   103 4390165                AMT 2018          0          0
15   103 4390164                AMT 2010          0          0
```

I tried to use melt, but it didn't work very well:

```
xxx <- reshape2::melt(xxx[[1]], id.vars = 'codigo')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, here is a code that should work for you:

```
# Tried recreating your dataframe
dt <- data.frame(estab = 103,
                 codigo = 4390160:4390174,
                 descricao = c("ANM 2003", "ANM 2004", "ANM BATERIA"),
                 "2021-02-01" = 0,
                 "2021-02-02" = 0)

dt <- reshape2::melt(dt, id.vars = c("estab", "codigo", "descricao"), variable.name = "Date", value.name = "Value")

# Make column into date
dt$Date <- gsub("X", "", dt$Date)
dt$Date <- as.Date(dt$Date, format = "%Y.%m.%d")

head(dt)
```

[image: Screenshot of output]

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be after something like the following.

```
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

pivot_longer(df, matches('\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}'),
             names_to = 'date',
             names_transform = list(date = ymd))

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   estab  codigo descricao   date       value
#   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>       <date>     <dbl>
# 1   103 4390160 ANM 2003    2021-02-01     0
# 2   103 4390160 ANM 2003    2021-02-02     0
# 3   103 4390161 ANM 2004 MF 2021-02-01     0
# 4   103 4390161 ANM 2004 MF 2021-02-02     0
# 5   103 4390162 ANM 2008 MF 2021-02-01     0
# 6   103 4390162 ANM 2008 MF 2021-02-02     0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(estab = c(103, 103, 103), codigo = c(4390160, 
4390161, 4390162), descricao = c("ANM 2003", "ANM 2004 MF", "ANM 2008 MF"
), `2021-02-01` = c(0, 0, 0), `2021-02-02` = c(0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `reshape`

```
out <- reshape(df1, direction = "long", varying = 4:5, sep = "")
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(estab = c(103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 
103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103), codigo = 4390160:4390174, 
    descricao = c("ANM 2003", "ANM 2004", "ANM BATERIA", "ANM 2003", 
    "ANM 2004", "ANM BATERIA", "ANM 2003", "ANM 2004", "ANM BATERIA", 
    "ANM 2003", "ANM 2004", "ANM BATERIA", "ANM 2003", "ANM 2004", 
    "ANM BATERIA"), X2021.02.01 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2021.02.02 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```